# RubyMine Remote Ruby Interpreter Error

Tags: ssh, ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I am trying to access my Ubuntu VM through SSH to use as a remote interpreter for RubyMine v5.0.1. However, whenever I successfully authenticate and point to my ruby location, it does not add the remote interpreter. The screen doesn't give any error messages which means that I am able to access the ruby interpreter.

[image]

Within the RubyMine log files, I see this information:

```
Executing ssh command: env "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" "PATH"="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" "RM_INFO"="RM-125.65" /usr/local/bin/ruby --disable-gems -e "puts $:" for administrator@192.168.1.250:22 
2013-02-19 00:32:49,705 [  35465]   INFO - emote.RubyRemoteProcessHandler - processWillTerminate():null 
2013-02-19 00:32:49,707 [  35467]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - sdk home directory must not bee null (Remote:ruby-1.9.3-p362: 1.9.3 (ssh://administrator@192.168.1.250:22/usr/local/bin/ruby)) 
java.lang.AssertionError: sdk home directory must not bee null (Remote:ruby-1.9.3-p362: 1.9.3 (ssh://administrator@192.168.1.250:22/usr/local/bin/ruby))
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.ruby.ruby.sdk.RubySdkUtil.unCygwinizePath(RubySdkUtil.java:348)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.ruby.ruby.sdk.RubySdkType.buildSdkLoadpath(RubySdkType.java:396)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.ruby.ruby.sdk.RubySdkType$1.run(RubySdkType.java:326)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.ruby.ruby.sdk.RubySdkType$2.run(RubySdkType.java:362)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$5.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:297)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:181)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:689)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$6.run(ApplicationImpl.java:462)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)
2013-02-19 00:32:49,711 [  35471]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JetBrains RubyMine 5.0  Build #RM-125.65 
2013-02-19 00:32:49,711 [  35471]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.7.0_10 
2013-02-19 00:32:49,711 [  35471]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 
2013-02-19 00:32:49,711 [  35471]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2013-02-19 00:32:49,711 [  35471]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Windows 8 
2013-02-19 00:32:49,712 [  35472]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action: EditorLineStart 
2013-02-19 00:32:49,713 [  35473]   INFO - esdk.transport.JschExecProcess - Executing ssh command: env "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" "PATH"="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" "RM_INFO"="RM-125.65" /usr/local/bin/ruby /home/administrator/.rubymine_helpers/rb/exec_with_work_dir.rb /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin/ruby -x /usr/local/bin/gem environment gempath for administrator@192.168.1.250:22 
2013-02-19 00:32:49,926 [  35686]   INFO - emote.RubyRemoteProcessHandler - processWillTerminate():null 
2013-02-19 00:32:49,928 [  35688]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - Error during dispatching of java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(47,48),absolute(1498,233),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on win0 
java.lang.AssertionError: sdk home directory must not bee null (Remote:ruby-1.9.3-p362: 1.9.3 (ssh://administrator@192.168.1.250:22/usr/local/bin/ruby))
```

Other than the mispelling of the word `be`, the thing that points out to me is this error message

`sdk home directory must not bee null`

However, I am not sure what or where it is expecting the sdk to be. I'm not sure what sdk it is expecting. Since my Ruby on Rails servers are hosted within linux, I really wanted to use the ruby interpreter within linux instead of a windows based one. (gems play nicer when the app is developed on the same platform as the server ie rmagick, carrierwave, etc.).

What do I need to do to complete this connection and to use the linux ruby interpreter from my Virtualized Ubuntu Development Server installation.

Unfortunately, I cannot run Ubuntu as my primary OS since I am often referencing to Windows based applications that run better on native Windows.

**EDIT**

They have released an update RubyMine 5.0.2 which addresses this issue. It is available as of 3/4/2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known problem that is already fixed, fix will be available in 5.0.2

Comment: Please provide a link to where you got this information.

Comment: Will accept answer if you can provide literature. I looked in the current bug report and did not see this mentioned at all. I've signed up for the EAP and am waiting for authorization to see if this issue has been fixed. I see on your profile that you are part of the development team. Any ideas what it is looking for? More details would be appreciated. Would I just need to create a symlink or something?